# MongoEngine - How to get files from GridFs using ObjectIDs

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, gridfs

I have a specific collection of documents when each document holds a file (using GridFS).

I used the aggregate method to retrieve specific documents from that collection.
The aggregate method returned me a list of documents, when each document is represented as a dictionary.
So when I try to get the file from the dict, it returns me an ObjectID Object (and not a file object as returned in the regular querying method).

The question is, how can I get the file object using this ObjectID?
To rephrase it, Is there an easy way to get the actual file object as shown in the [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/gridfs.html) using only the ObjectID (without getting involved in the merging of the file chunks in the GridFS)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this is to use the GridFSProxy object directly and put the file Object ID as the parameter:

```
import mongoengine
.
.
file_obj = mongoengine.GridFSProxy(FileID)
```